# Hot to get opened window count in an Electron app?

Tags: electron

Is there any API provided by Electron to let get the current opened BrowserWindow count?

I did not find the method via the app API. Or can I get how many renderProcess is running now?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`BrowserWindow.getAllWindows`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowgetallwindows) and use `isVisible` per instance optionally:

```
  let count = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()
  .filter(b => {
    return b.isVisible()
  })
  .length
```

---

For number of renderer processes (which is not necessarily the same as BrowserWindow count) you can use [`webContents.getAllWebContents()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#webcontentsgetallwebcontents)